# Extra boot options in BIOS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bios, ntfs, uefi

I've got two extra boot options in my BIOS called `ubuntu`.  There is a picture of them for reference, and they've got a portable hard drive icon in UEFI BIOS.  Does anyone know how to get rid of them?

I thought they were hiding on my hard drive but they're not. Booting to them does nothing and they just sit there, staring, taunting.
[image: a picture of them]

Comment: just take a photo and add a picture, you should really be able to do that when you submit the question or just after.

Comment: I'm not sure me taking a picture of two extra boot options is going to drastically improve your understanding of their existence.  I've been busy, and didn't prioritize this because I felt it could be understood in its current form.

Comment: obviously it can possibly be understood in its current form, nobody disputed that. But there are reasons why a picture helps. And you yourself wrote "(will add picture)" at the bottom of your post.

Comment: And I will, I just can't afford to turn my computer off right now, at least for a few hours.